# gstreamer library unresolved include

Tags: gstreamer

I wrote a simple C code with GStreamer libs (gstreamer example code manual ref)

My GStreamer headers are located at `/usr/include/gstreamer-0.10/gst`.

Thus, I wrote the following line in my C code:

```
#include "gstreamer-0.10/gst/gst.h"
```

When I compiled, I have this error:

> there are unresolved includes inside

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you...

Comment: The [gst manual](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-helloworld-compilerun.html) states to use this `gcc -Wall helloworld.c -o helloworld $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-0.10)`

Answer (score 4):

If you use the standard C compiler flags given by `pkg-config gstreamer-0.10 --cflags`, you should need only `#include <gst/gst.h>` in your source code. To help yourself, you can use a simple Makefile (some simple example [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1164725))

Answer (score 0):

in my Qt project-file i use following:

```
   CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
    PKGCONFIG += glib-2.0 \
        gstreamer-0.10 \
        gstreamer-interfaces-0.10
```

so i suppose you have to tell your compiler to use these pkg-configs (*.pc): glib-2.0, gstreamer-0.10, gstreamer-interfaces-0.10